# Converging sequence to least upper bound

Tags: coq

Given a non-empty subset of the real numbers `E : R -> Prop`, the completeness axiom gives a least upper bound `l` of `E`.

Is there a constructive function

```
lub_approx_seq (E : R -> Prop) (l : R)
  : is_lub E l -> forall n:nat, { x:R | E x /\ l-1/n < x }
```

In classical mathematics we would argue that for all `n:nat, l-1/n` is not an upper bound, so there exists an `x` such that `E x /\ l-1/n < x`.

But in constructive mathematics, `~forall` (not an upper bound) is weaker than `exists`.

If it is not possible for a general subset `E`, are there conditions on `E` that make it possible ?

**EDIT**

I'm particularly interested in the case where `E` is a downward-infinite interval. Then the converging sequence is simply `fun n:nat => l-1/n` and what remains to be proved is :

```
Lemma lub_approx (E : R -> Prop) (l : R)
  : is_lub E l
    -> (forall x y : R, x < y -> E y -> E x) (* interval *)
    -> forall x : R, x < l -> E x
```